# Replacing entire string cells in column with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I have a pandas dataframe containing numerous columns with assay values (geochemical concentrations). Some of them are empty (NaN), some are values (ex. 3.2), and some are strings (ex. <0.03). My goal is to strip out all of the sting cells containing ranges (ex. <0.03) and replace them with 0, and cast them all to floats.
I've tried various forms of the contains and replace method with no success:
Example column is titled 'Ag ICP-MS mg/kg 0.03'.

`df_clean.loc[df['Ag ICP-MS mg/kg 0.03'].contains('<'), 'Ag ICP-MS mg/kg 0.03'] = '000'`

Or limited success only removing the '<':

`df_clean.replace('(<)','',regex=True, inplace = True)`

Comment: It would be beneficial if you could share the input dataframe (an excerpt). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pandas.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
df['Ag ICP-MS mg/kg 0.03'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Ag ICP-MS mg/kg 0.03'], errors='coerce').fillna(0)
```